# `str_replace` not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress

I do adjustments to a wordpress theme and want to change the title output for a custom post type. To be precise, I want to remove `Work Type` from it:

```
echo str_replace('Work Type ', '', wp_title(''));
```

**Current output:**

> Work Type Title - What a site

**Expected:**

> Title - What a site

Notes:

- Simply echoing `wp_title('')` results in the *current output* as well
- If I do `wp_title()` I get **Work Type » Title »**

Comment: What if you try to `echo str_replace('Work Type', '', wp_title(''));` ? (Without that whitespace at the end)? Just to make sure that it is not a special unicode whitespace character

Comment: echo trim(str_replace('Work Type', '', wp_title(''))) should work i think.

Comment: I tried it with single letters (i.e. `e` or `o `) and it doesn't work. I plan to `trim()` if it finally works, but it doesn't if I include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem is that your wp_title gives echo instead of return:

Look this wp_title() function:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L0

Your wp_title returns echo instead return so you need to change:

```
 wp_title('some_title', false); // false means will return value instead echo
```

so...

```
 echo str_replace('Work Type ', '', wp_title('Your title', false));
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm surprised I didn't come across this while researching. _Welp…_ This works indeed.